# jQuery .append() adding dimensionless elements, appear only on window resize

Tags: jquery, append, rendering, dimension

I'm trying to add elements onfocus and remove them onfocusout/onblur.

The pattern is:

- On the first onfocus event the elements are added and visible, they are removed onfocusout/onblur with no problem

- After the first onfocus event, the elements are added ***in the DOM but are dimensionless** until the window resizes, then the elements regain their dimension*.

I wrote the exact same code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/livvyjeffs/8HZLX/7/) and interestingly enough, could not replicate the problem. It works perfectly in the fiddle.

The project is complex and has many jquery functions, so I can't replicate the entire experience on a fiddle.

Any idea on what can cause this? Everything in the DOM is exactly the same between the versions that work and don't work, they are just rendered differently and I don't understand exactly how that can be.

HTML Code:

```
<textarea class="starter_comment" rows="1" placeholder="leave a comment.."></textarea>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.starter_comment').focus(function () {

    if ($(this).attr("status") !== "open") {
        $(this).attr("status", "open");
        $(this).attr("rows", 5);
        $(this).parent().append("<button type='submit'>Submit</button><span class='cancel_comment' onclick='cancel_comment();'>Cancel</span>");

    }
});

$('.starter_comment').focusout(function () {
    $('.starter_comment').attr("status", "closed");
    $('.starter_comment').attr("rows", 1);
    $('.cancel_comment').remove();
    $('button').remove();

});
```

Comment: is there any other frameworks used in the page like a css framework... look at the parent elements to see whether there are any css rules like hight/width set which might be causing the problem

Comment: using your browser debugging tools... comment out one by one rule and see whether the elements are appearing

Comment: are you adding this textarea on dynamically ?